# Compiling android native app calling ndk-build from eclipse, on ubuntu

Tags: eclipse, android-ndk

On ubuntu 11.10 I installed eclipse from repositories, installed adt and cdt plugins. I am able to compile the hello-jni example using command line, but i would like to use eclipse for the task.

I followed the guide here: http://mhandroid.wordpress.com/2011/01/23/using-eclipse-for-android-cc-development/ and defined a PATH variable in eclipse preferences  (window->preferences->c/c++->environment), pointing to the ndk-r7b folder. But the project won't buid. I get this error:

```
(Cannot run program "ndk-build"
(in directory "/home/athos/android/ndk-r7b/samples/hello-jni"):
java.io.IOException: 
error=2, File o directory non esistente)
```

(last line should be "no such file or directory" in english)

If I specify "${PATH}/ndk-build" or "/home/athos/android/ndk-r7b/ndk-build"  as the build command. i get this:

```
/home/lavoro/android/ndk-r7b/ndk-build
ERROR: Cannot find 'make' program. Please install Cygwin make package
/home/lavoro/android/ndk-r7b/ndk-build: 40: dirname: not found
or define the GNUMAKE variable to point to it.
```

If I define the GNUMAKE variable in window->preferences->c/c++->environment i get this:

```
ERROR: Your GNUMAKE variable is defined to an invalid name: /usr/bin/make
Please fix it to point to a valid make executable (e.g. /usr/bin/make)
```

Which is funny, since It suggests the exact same directory I indicated. Make is installed and present at the indicated location.

What am I missing?

Comment: did you get the solution to  this ?

Comment: no, and in the meanwhile I became used to the command line interface :/

Answer (score 0):

It's a bit ugly, but you can always put

```
/fully/qualified/path/to/ndk-build
```

In your build command.

Comment: sorry for the delay, i just saw this. As i said, I already tried with the fully qualified path (/home/athos/android/ndk-r7b/ndk-build)